# Floating numbers C++ , How to add "f" in the end for each element of array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, floating-point, floating

I just opend  filename.file , saved each floating number in vector "vertices" but they are saved as ineteger numbers.Need to convert all numbers correctly to float.
For example : from "1" to "1.00000f" or atleast from "1" to "1.0f".

```
/////filename.file
...
v 1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
...
//////


std::vector<float> vertices;

std::ifstream file(filename); 

    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(file, line))
    {

        std::istringstream iss(line);

        std::string result;

        if (std::getline(iss, result, ' '))
        {

            if (result == "v")
            {



                while (std::getline(iss, token, ' '))
                {
                    std::istringstream iss1(token);

                    if (std::getline(iss1, word))
                    {
                        float word_float = std::stof(word);

                        //std::cout << word_float << std::endl;
                        vertices.push_back(word_float);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

//Look what I got
for(std::size_t i = 0 ; i < vertices.size(); i++) {
 std::cout << vertices[i] << " ";
}
```

/* Each element
1
-1
1
...

// But these numbers should be saved exactly so

1.000000f
-1.000000f
1.000000f
...
*/

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how floating point numbers work. When assigned to a `float`, all of `1`, `1.0f`, `1.00000f` yield exactly the same number. If `f` or the exact amount of zeroes after the `.` matter, you should store the numbers as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want something on the order of:

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(5) << value << "f";
```

for example:

```
float values[] = { 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f };

for (auto const &value : values)
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(5) << value << "f\t";
```

Result:

```
1.00000f    -1.00000f   1.00000f
```

Comment: this stuff works for output , but I need to save in vector  these numbers(1.00000f    -1.00000f   1.00000f) instead  of (1 , -1 , 1)

Comment: @AlexTsypurdei: What you save in the vector has whatever precision the type supports, so with a `float` it'll typically have around 6 decimal digits of precision. By default, however, trailing zeros won't show when you print them out.